# Is there a way to determine if a function was called from a pthread?

Tags: pthreads

I am developing a library backend application that needs to handles calls from both pthreads and non-pthreads, and in particular I want to set thread specific state in the library. Note, I have no control over the application that links the library and it may be using pthreads, not pthreads, or might be calling library functions from a pthread and no a pthread. I need a means to determie whether a running function was called from a pthread or not.

When I call `pthread_getspecific()` in a non-pthreads context, NULL is returned even right after calling `pthread_setpecific()`. Is this a documented behavior I can rely on? Also, is there another function I can call to determine if the caller is running in a pthread? I looked at `pthread_self()`, but that returns a rather large value from a non-pthread that I assume is supposed to be opaque.

Comment: What exactly are "non-pthreads" in your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

> I am developing a library backend application that needs to handles calls from both pthreads and non-pthreads,

No code is executed outside the context of a thread.  A process starts with one thread, and (on a system that provides the pthreads API) can start new ones via `pthread_create()`.  Such additional threads are not different in kind from the initial one.

> and in particular I want to set thread specific state in the library.

Ok.  Shouldn't be a problem.

> I need a means to determie whether a running function was called from a pthread or not.

```c
_Bool is_called_from_a_thread(void) {
    return 1;
}
```

> When I call `pthread_getspecific()` in a non-pthreads context, NULL is returned even right after calling `pthread_setpecific()`.

POSIX does not define anything that could reasonably be characterized as a "non-pthreads context" on a system that supports pthreads.  And what you describe sounds surprising in any context.  Consider this program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(void) {
    pthread_key_t key;
    int result = pthread_key_create(&key, NULL);
    if (result != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_key_create: %s\n", strerror(result));
        return 1;
    }

    char *data = NULL;
    result = pthread_setspecific(key, "the data");
    if (result != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_setspecific: %s\n", strerror(result));
        return 1;
    }

    data = pthread_getspecific(key);
    if (!data) {
        puts("no TSD");
    } else {
        puts(data);
    }
}
```

When I compile and run it in my environment, it prints:

> the data

, demonstrating that the application's initial thread indeed can set and successfully retrieve TSD.  I cannot explain why you think you observe different in your environment, since you have not presented any code.  Possibilities include, in approximate order of likelihood:

- your code is buggy
- your C library genuinely refuses to set TSD for the initial thread, and the call to `pthread_setspecific()` therefore fails (and I guess you didn't check for that).  I don't think that would conform to POSIX, but I'm not prepared to argue chapter and verse for that.
- your C library is buggy, accepting the `pthread_setspecific()` call in the initial thread without error, but not subsequently retrieving the TSD via a call to `pthread_getspecific()`.

> Is this a documented behavior I can rely on?

No, **it absolutely is not documented** that `pthread_setspecific()` will fail in a process's initial thread, and certainly not that it might succeed, yet subsequent `pthread_getspecific()` calls for the same key would nevertheless fail to retrieve the data.

No, **you cannot rely on that behavior**, as the above program does not reproduce it for me.

> Also, is there another function I can call to determine if the caller is running in a pthread?

See my `is_called_from_a_thread()` function, above.  For what that's worth.

You should definitely be checking the return values of your function calls for error indicators.  Possibly the distinction you want to make is really whether `pthread_setspecific()` fails.  And if so, perhaps you want to distinguish among different error numbers.

> I looked at pthread_self(), but that returns a rather large value from a non-pthread that I assume is supposed to be opaque.

*That* is documented.  `pthread_t` values are indeed intended to be treated as opaque. Substantially no specific requirements are placed on that type, such that you can even rely on being able to interpret its values as "large" or "small".

Comment: Agreed.  There is no need to determine if your calling program only has a single thread (a situation which could change at any time, anyway) - if your library works fine when called from multiple threads, it'll also work fine when called from a single one.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of GCC/GLIBC under Linux, there is the `__thread` keyword to define thread specific variables. So, you can use it in your library to tag thread specific variables. They will be instantiated in MT environment. For example, here is an integer defined as a thread specific variable:

```c
static __thread int th_var;
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not speak to any of the OP's questions.